# Sending GET value to URL without parameters and extra characters?

Tags: php, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I'm currently working on a CodeIgniter application but I need the search functionality to be more readable, for both humans and CodeIgniter.

Here's what I currently get as the URL when submitting the form.

```
http://mydomain.com/search/?query=batman
```

And here's what I'm looking to end up with.

```
http://mydomain.com/search/batman
```

I'm not great with mod rewrites, but I imagine that's the route I'll need to take?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: @BeatAlex That's not what +1 is for but...

Comment: Do you need routing? http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

Comment: I would not do this, using a `GET` string is the correct way to do a search.  This way you can tell search engines and your analytics to track or ignore these pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a very nice method but:

What if you make it a `POST` and put the variable into a separate controller. eg `search($s)`

```
public function search($s){
    header('Location:http://yoursite.com/whatever/search/'. $s);
}
```

This should give you the result you need.

Comment: This method might not have been the cleanest, but it works! :)

Thanks.

Comment: @LewisHill : You should have tried once what I suggested, its not a clean method to use as I see(just a suggestion). Mine is the same process but a more suitable one with `pagination` too.

Answer (score 1):

You should use mod_rewrite, creating a script .htaccess in your script path:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /index.php?query=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Take a look to mod_rewrite docs for more infos
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: I like the look of this method, to be honest, I've tried them all and nothing has worked as of yet.

Here's my .htaccess as it stands, I already have it removing the function name.

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]`

I tried adding your solution to the bottom of my current .htaccess, but nothing happened.

I notice you have /index.php in the script, but my URL looks something like `http://localhost/dev/comiq/search/?search=batman`.

Is this a problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the onsubmit() event with javascript and then redirect to the url you want..

```
$('#myform').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var value = $('#input').val()
    window.location = 'http://mydomain.com/search/' + value;
})
```

Of course, your controller will have to look like this:

```
class Search extends CI_Controller
{
   public function index($term)
   {
      // code code
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First change the `form method` to `POST` and in your search function you can then do something like this:

```
function search(){
    if( $this->input->post(null) ){
        $keyword    = $this->input->post('keyword');
        #do you processing with the post
    }else{
        $keyword    = $this->uri->segment(3);
    }

    #for pagination
    $config['base_url']     = base_url()."controller/search/".$keyword."/page/";
    $config['uri_segment']  = 5;
}
```

Comment: This is good but I think he wants to stick with GET + the reasons @Christopher pointed out above